# How to connect to heroku server app to postgres database after upgrading from hobby to standard with node.js, express (generator) and knex

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, knex.js, heroku-postgres

I'm upgrading my heroku postgres db from hobby (free) to standard-0 (paid) because I am nearing the row limitation for the hobby plan, and can't get an SSL to issue or "stick" to my app so that it will work.

I successfully followed the pg:copy instructions in the Heroku docs, but after doing so, the app can not access the new db. I am able to access it with POSTICO.

Research indicates that this is an SSL issue, so I upgraded to hobby dynos (heroku ps:resize web=hobby), which should automatically generate and assign an SSL cert to my app domain, per Heroku docs.

But, when I do this, and then run:

```
heroku certs
```

I get:  my-app-name has no SSL certificates.
Use heroku certs:add CRT KEY to add one

When I run:

```
heroku certs:auto
```

I get:

Enabling Automatic Certificate Management... starting. See status with heroku certs:auto or wait until active with heroku certs:auto:wait
=== Your certificate will now be managed by Heroku.  Check the status by running

```
heroku certs:auto
```

But running

```
heroku certs
```

still gives: my-app-name has no SSL certificates

Running

```
heroku certs:auto:wait
```

I get: nothing...just a new line on my command line

Running

```
heroku certs:generate my-app-name.herokuapp.com
```

I get:

Your key and certificate signing request have been generated.
Submit the CSR in 'my-app-name.herokuapp.com.csr' to your preferred certificate authority.

I don't know what that means, and besides Heroku docs say this should be done for me.

ALSO:  I did add the ssl: true key value pair to my production object in knexfile.js

```
production: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: true
  },
```

Comment: You're conflating two separate issues, I believe. The `heroku certs` commands you're issuing are related to incoming client connections to your `web` processes. That's an entirely separate issue from failed connections from your app services to the database. Are you able to add the actual db connection error to your question?

Comment: Thank you , @RangerRanger.  My initial research led me to other posts about similar problems where upgrading to the standard-0 plan resulted in a failure to connect with the DB, and a couple were resolved by forcing SSL in different ways. Turns out that forcing the connection differently resolved this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up opening a help ticket with Heroku.  After ensuring that the pg:copy process was in fact followed correctly, I was given this suggestion, which solved the issue, by a very knowledgeable Heroku engineer named, Taylor Jones.

> It seems that your Knex instance still isn't forcing SSL despite your
>   configuration specifying to do so. Try adding the following config
>   variable to your app:

```
heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=require
```

> This should add an extra layer of enforcement around your SSL
>   connection to your Postgres instance. Let me know if this doesn't work
>   either.